# Python, concat string with __dict__ output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to debug a python script

seems some things aren't simple in python

`sys.exit( 'hello world' + self.__dict__)`

gives me

`TypeError: must be str, not dict`

How can I do

`sys.exit( 'hello world' + self.__dict__)`

so it does not give me an error?

Comment: What are you trying to do, precisely?

Comment: Clearly, you are trying to concatenate string to dict. Any sample dict? what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: The context is different but the solutions are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate a `string` with the string representation of a `dictionary`.

```
sys.exit( 'hello world' + str(self.__dict__))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is pretty straight-forward. You're trying to concat a dict to a string which makes no sense.

`_dict_` does not return a string, this is from the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) :

> A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s
>   (writable) attributes.

Comment: sorry mate, but I asked for a solution, not what the error means

Comment: don't be sorry, just more clear next time you ask a question. With your rep I'm sure you already know that asking _what is the solution?_ is not a good enough question.

Comment: By the way, go see the accepted answer of the duplicate. Seems pretty close to what I have. If you need a working example please make it clear what output you are expecting.

Comment: hehe no need to be upset. `a + b` results in `error`. "What is the solution?" is not understandable.. I see. Well this is the python community, not used to that yet. You were even not the only one not understanding it. I guess python people think different

Comment: I guess we just try to be humble and help people as much as we can. Something you probably can't understand. Sad to have taken some of my free time trying to help someone that is too selfish just to say thank you. Anyway, have a good day __mate__ I'm not wasting one more second on your thread.

Comment: what made you write that? what did I write that you turned so salty? that i'm not used to the python community? it wasn't meant that way. Have a great day buddy